# Как удалить определенные файлы после закрытия окна программы tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Можно ли каким-то образом удалить определенные файлы после закрытия окна программы tkinter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно удаление поставить в строке ниже той, где вызывается `mainloop` (эта функция работает все время, пока существует главное окно; когда окно закрывается, выполнение функции `mainloop` завершается):

```
import tkinter as tk
import os

root = tk.Tk()

# Создаем файл
with open("some_file.txt", "w") as file:
    pass

root.mainloop()

# Удаляем файл
os.remove("some_file.txt")
```

Либо привязать к "событию" закрытия выполнение какой-то функции:

```
import tkinter as tk
import os

root = tk.Tk()

with open("some_file.txt", "w") as file:
    pass

def on_closing():
    os.remove("some_file.txt")

root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)

root.mainloop()
```

Также можно привязать действие к завершению приложения (не обязательно оконного) с помощью стандартного модуля [ataxit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html):

```
import tkinter as tk
import os
import atexit

root = tk.Tk()

with open("some_file.txt", "w") as file:
    pass

def on_closing():
    os.remove("some_file.txt")

atexit.register(on_closing)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

А причем тут tkinter к файлу или его удалению?
Удаление файлов в Python выполняется функцией

```
os.remove(file_path)
```

из соответствующей библиотеки и никакого отношения к tkinter не имеет.